# The "python" CLI executable seems to ignore path hierarchy

Tags: macos, terminal, python

I have the following strange situation on my (freshly installed El Capitan, otherwise empty) Mac.

I noticed that `/usr/bin/python` defaults to python 2.7 (still), and the new SIP security system "protects" me from replacing it with a symlink to point to python3 (which I installed in `/usr/local/bin`). I noticed that `/usr/local/bin` shows up first on the path:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

So I thought great, I'll just add a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` called `python` and point it to python3.

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/bin
...
lrwxr-xr-x   ... python -> /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x   ... python3 -> ../Cellar/python3/3.5.0/bin/python3
```

And this is reflected by `which`

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

But when I actually use it, it goes back to the native python2.7

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

What gives? Is OS X tinkering with my `$PATH` and not telling me? What steps can I take to ensure I know what command is actually going to be run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try closing your terminal window, and making a new one. The shell only actually checks where commands are located on launch, and doesn't check again if it thinks it knows where the command is located. It's a performance boost in scripts, so generally a good idea.

Comment: Is this specific to OS X? it's not like I changed the path or anything...

Comment: No. Scripts would take much longer to run if it had to check where each command is located every single time a command is used, so it generally creates a list at runtime, then just reuses that list for any commands processed, unless it doesn't find something in the list, then it checks again. I don't believe there's a way to convince the shell that it's wrong, if it thinks it knows where Python is located, without restarting it.

Comment: The caching is a property of  bash

Answer (score 2):

If your shell is bash, then you can use the `type` and `hash` builtins to manipulate its cache of executable paths (as shown in [How do I clear Bash's cache of paths to executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables)):

```
# to clear the whole cache
hash -r

# to only remove one cached command
hash -d python
```